# Using xml2js to build xml with equal child key?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm using [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) to build a .xml from my registers. For each element, i need to set the key with same name, **example: key: product with an attribute id**

The expected result:

```
<products>
  <product id="H12896">
    <name>Grand Hotel New York</name>
    <price>120.80</price>
  </product>
  <product id="...">
    ...
  </product>
</products>
```

My code:

```
var products = [];

_.each(list, function(element) {

    var obj = {
      name: element.title,
      price: element.price,
    };

    products.push(obj);


});


var builder = new xml2js.Builder({rootName: 'products'});
var xml = builder.buildObject(products);
fs.writeFile('pacotes.xml', xml, (err) => {
  if (err) throw (err);
});
```

Output result:

```
<products>
  <0>
    <name>Mountain Do</name>
    <price>0</price>
  </0>
</products>
```

I checked the documentation, but nothing yet. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using XMLBuilder? https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/

XMLBuilder seems much better suited for what you're wanting to do, and is much, much more popular (ex: 4 million downloads in the last month). xml2js is better suited for reading in JavaScript, but XMLBuilder is definitely what you'd want to use.

And if I'm reading correctly... xml2js is just building on XMLBuilder anyway.

```
var builder = require('xmlbuilder'),
    xml = builder.create('root'),
    products = xml.ele('products'),
    product;

_.each(list, function(element) {
    product = products.ele('product');
    product.att('id', element.id);
    product.ele('name', null, element.name);
    product.ele('price', null, element.price);
});

xml = xml.end();
fs.writeFile('pacotes.xml', xml, (err) => {
    if (err) throw (err);
});
```

Comment: thank you. Actually the only package i knew about xml was xml2js. This one was really easy to code. thanks man.

Comment: you can also do it with xml2js please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993540/8873235

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a list of objects and use the name that you want to use as the key:

```
const productList = [
  { name: 'foo', price: 30 },
  { name: 'bar', price: 5 },
  { name: 'baz', price: 87 },
];

const obj = { product: [] }

productList.forEach(element => obj.product.push({
  name: element.name,
  price: element.price,
}));

const builder = new xml2js.Builder({rootName: 'products'});
const xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
console.log(xml);
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name/>
    <price>30</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name/>
    <price>5</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name/>
    <price>87</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: it should be `element.name` instead of `element.title`. That's why name node does not get any value...

Comment: For those who want to keep `xml2js` this should be the accepted answer